# resizing windows instance in openstack - disk wont resize

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-glance

Openstack resize flavor in windows image show no error. CPU and Memory will increase but the disk won't.
no error log. in the instance description it shows the new flavor but the disk won't resize.
I check the disk with mini tool partition wizard [image shown in tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYXqw.png)

It should be 80 Gig but only shows the first 20G disk that was created

Comment: can you please open the disk management on the vm and check there?

Comment: @djdomi I uploaded it

Answer (score 0):

@djdomi
this my disk mgmt pix
[Diskmgmt.msc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UICVe.png)

Comment: in many case you need live CD and boot using rescue mode to resize the disk.